# Why do we use $\Omega$ to Represent a Subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, math-history

From Wade's "Introduction to Analysis":

> NOTE: Because French mathematicians (e.g., Borel, Jordan, and Lebesgue) did fundamental work on the connection between analysis and set theory, and ensemble is French for set, analysts frequently use E to represent a general set.

Most undergraduate analysis texts use $E$ for a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but in complex analysis and PDE we tend to use $\Omega$ almost exclusively (at least in the texts I have read). Is there any rhyme or reason behind using $\Omega$, and does anyone know the history leading to the ubiquity of $\Omega$ to mean a region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for PDE specifically?

Comment: maybe this: $\Omega$ in Greek corresponds to $O$ in English, and $O$ might stand for "open"